# Similar child component does not load from router outlet

Tags: html, http, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am creating a file upload front end and have a grid view for the files and a list view for the files. They both are children component from a parent Preview component. The type script files are almost the exact same thing for both the grid view and the list view.When the user loads the page with row in the url, the page will load and everything works. When the page is loaded with the grid in the url, the page will crash. Here is the error: [image]

I cannot show the code, but I can try my best to give an overview. The parent component has only two directives, the children components. I route to them in the html associated to the parent component. When the parent component is loaded, I subscribe to a list of file items. In that subscription I have the JSON response which I parse into a Object that contains the data. At this point, I have the correct data. I can console log that data. The Object I have is then filled with the JSON data.

Again, this works for one child component, but not the other. In the grid component the error posted above is show on load. It says that the property items is undefined. My guess is that with the grid component, the html that is trying to reach the "items" array is loaded before the subscription is done loading in the parent component. If that is the issue, how do I deal with it?

In addition, when I place a debugger in the getItems method which the child component html is calling, the error above appears prior to the debugger start.

Code for grid html - CHILD 1

```
<div *ngIf="isEmpty()" class="full-height">
  <app-upload></app-upload>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="container-width" *ngFor="let file of service.getItems()">
    <div class="preview-ico-container">
      <img *ngIf="needsLabelIcon(file)" class="img-responsive label-icon-size" src="app/resources/img/ico/{{file.ext}}.ico" alt="">
      <img *ngIf="file.type=='image'" class="img-responsive preview-ico-size" alt="Responsive image" src='{{ file.dataUri }}'>
      <img *ngIf="file.type!='image'" class="img-responsive preview-ico-only" alt="Responsive image" src="app/resources/img/ico/{{file.ext}}.ico">
    </div>
    <div class="preview-img-name-container">
      {{ file.fileName }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code for row html - CHILD 2

```
  <tr class="table-content" *ngFor="let file of service.getItems()">
```

Code for preview typescript - PARENT

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getItems();
  }

  getItems() {
    this.service.Get().subscribe((data) => {
      debugger  //TESTING
      console.log(data);  //TESTING
      // SetModelView takes a json response and parses it into a an object I
      //   made. This is also where the items array is set, which
      //   service.getItems() looks at in both the child components
      this.service.setModelView(data);
      this.isNext_Prev();
    });
  }

  isNext_Prev() {
    if (this.service.modelView && this.service.modelView._links.next) {
      this.nextDisplay = "inline-block";
    } else {
      this.nextDisplay = "none";
    }
    if (this.service.modelView && this.service.modelView._links.previous) {
      this.prevDisplay = "inline-block";
    } else {
      this.prevDisplay = "none";
    }
  }
```

When I place the debugger in my service in the Get request method which communicates with my API, the error already exist. So, before the first http requst, grid child component is trying to load the file items array.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: Please share preview-grid.component.html

Comment: Hard to tell. Try to go to the `PriviewGridComponent.template.js.77` which you showed us in screenshot and also show the code

Comment: I found a possible solution? Im just not sure how this could be the case if it is working for one component but not the other. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503322/iterate-through-an-array-of-objects-angular-2

Comment: What does `service.getItems()` return? I find this confusing because `PARENT` also contains a `getItems` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to an observable you need to use the `| async` pipe

```
<div class="container-width" *ngFor="let file of service.getItems() | async">
```