# Iterate through an array of objects Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

Can anyone help what I am doing incorrect, anything missing?
I am getting undefined for --'this.ack.length'

```
this._activeChannelService.requestChannelChange(this.selectedchannel.channelName)
        .subscribe(
            ack  => {
                this.ack= ack;
                console.log(" test:  ", this.ack.length);
            },
            err => {
            console.log(err);
        });enter code here
```

ack is of time
 ack:Iack[];

Iack has two field of type string. result and message
I need to iterate through array of Iack[] to get the result and message
if message=success then call the another service

### service

```
requestChannelChange (name: string): Observable<Iack[]> {
    alert('in servicerequestChannelChange');
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let postchannelname = "channelName=" + name;
    let requestt = new IRequest(name);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(requestt));
    return this._http.post(this._activateChangeUrl, JSON.stringify(requestt),{ headers: headers })
     //.map(this.extractData)
        .map((res:Response) => res.json() as Iack[])
        .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us content of `_activeChannelService`?

Comment: echonax- I just updated the quesion to provide ack.

Comment: – Matej Maloča - I have updated toprovide service content

Comment: I can see ask is coming and being printed on the console

Comment: the JSON printed on console is All: {"result":"Channel Change","message":"ERROR"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here` is executed before `this.ack= ack;` is executed

This is a function

```
        ack  => {
            this.ack= ack;
            console.log(" test:  ", this.ack.length);
        }
```

that you pass to `subscribe(...)` and the observable calls it when the data arrives which can take a looong time when it's a call to a server.

`enter code here` is executed immediately.

Comment: appreciate your help.s there any way I can read the ack value after getting from service?

Comment: I looked at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503322/iterate-through-an-array-of-objects-angular-2/41260887#41260887

Comment: You can read it from within the callback, you can bind to it from the view (Angular updates the binding when the value becomes available, you can use `ack?.someProp` to avoid exceptions while the value is not yet available`) You can use `.map(...)` instead of `.subscribe(...)` and then use `this.getChannel().subscribe(...)` and access it there in the callback you pass to subscribe (assuming `getChannel`) is the name of the method that contains `this._activeChannelService.requestChannelChange(...)` - this needs to be prefixed with `return` to work)

Comment: can you please provide example of callback. also this contradict -- use .map instead of .subscribe? and then call back on .subscribe.  Appreciate your help?

Comment: I don't have the time just now. If you call `subscribe(...)` the observable is executed and a `Subscription` is returned. If you call `.map(...)` instead of `subscribe(...)` (while passing the same callback - only one though - none for error or success) then an `Observable` is returned that can be subscribed to. There should be enough tutorials out there like http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Comment: https://aigeec.com/angularjs-2-do-something-when-my-observable-is-complete/#observable-has-completed

Comment: tried something like this - but no joy https://aigeec.com/angularjs-2-do-something-when-my-observable-is-complete/#observable-has-completed

Comment: this._activeChannelService.requestChannelChange(this.selectedchannel.channelName)
            .subscribe(
                ack  => {
                    this.ack= ack;},
                err => {
                console.log(err);},
                () => alert(this.ack.length)
        );-- no joy for this.ack.length

Comment: What is the output if you use `this.ack` instead of `this.ack.length`?

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: An object doesn't have a `length`. Use better `console.log(this.ack)` instead of `alert()` for better debugging possibilities.

Comment: thanks for your help  Günter Zöchbauer- its all fine now-  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use observable in your TS service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IPost } from './IPost';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class PostServices {

    private _webApiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:62806/v1/Posts"
    private _http : Http;

    constructor(http : Http){
        this._http = http;
    }   

    getAll(): Observable<IPost[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._webApiBaseUrl + '/all', this.getHeaders())
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .do(data => console.log(`All Data: \n ${ JSON.stringify(data) }`))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }   

    private handleError(error: Response){
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }    

    private getHeaders()
    {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Authorization", ""); 
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }

}
```

Usage in your TS class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IPost } from './IPost';
import { PostServices } from './posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: IPost[];
  errorMessage: string;

  private _postService: PostServices;
  constructor(postService: PostServices) {
    this._postService = postService;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this._postService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
      data => {this.posts = data; console.log("data.length: " + data.length)}, // here
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error 
      );

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check for success within the service subscription. An observable is an asynchronous call, so any calls you want to make regarding the data in that async call must be made within it to remain a safe call.

So, make your seconds service call, within the subscription.